# WFS bbox behavior for longitudes >= 360 degrees

Tags: wfs, ogc, bbox

I have a question regarding the OGC WFS specification (2.x and unfinished 3.x).

Let's say I have a WFS feature with longitude 0°.

If I make WFS query with bbox with minx = 359° and maxx = 361°, should it - according to the specification - return my feature?
In other words, should I expect, that 0° = 360°?

I'm also curious about the opposite functionality.
Given there is a service containing feature with longitude 360°, should this feature be returned through WFS query with bbox between -1° and +1°?

I'm not asking about particular technologies, but more about the expected behavior, according to the specification.

Comment: I suspect it would depend on the projection of the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For WFS 3.0 (core) in draft it will not return a feature, because WFS 3.0 core only has one CRS (http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/OGC/1.3/CRS84), and for that CRS valid longitudes are +/- 180